# How do I increase the Nginx timeout for an Elastic Beanstalk deployed app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a `flask` app that I am deploying with elastic beanstalk. In my `env.yaml`, I have:

```
...
  aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate:
    RollingUpdateType: Health
    Timeout: PT30M
...
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:command:
    BatchSize: "30"
    BatchSizeType: Percentage
    Timeout: 2000
```

But when my app starts up (with `application.py`), I get an error:

```
[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:11232)
[11232] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11232)
[11324] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11324
```

What can I do to increase the timeout? I tried setting up a `01.nginx.timeout.config` with:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01.nginx.timeout.conf":
     mode: "000644"
     owner: root
     group: root
     content: |
       proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
       proxy_send_timeout 600s; 
       proxy_read_timeout 600s; 
       fastcgi_send_timeout 600s; 
       fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
container_commands:
  nginx_reload:
     command: "sudo service nginx reload"
```

but that gives an error about `ngnix reload` failing.

What can I do?

Comment: shuldn't it be `sudo systemctl restart nginx`?

Comment: Yup - that did it. If you post as an answer, I can accept.

Comment: Thanks and glad to hear. Answer added :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the **solution** was to use:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

in place of

```
sudo service nginx reload
```